# Getting not a group by expression while using listagg function

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
CREATE TABLE source_det (
    e_id       NUMBER(10),
    sys_name   VARCHAR2(20),
    ref_id     NUMBER(10),
    sys_other  VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(11,'SOURCE',992,null);
INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(11,'SOURCE',637,null);
INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(11,'SOURCE',null,'Manual');
INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(11,'TARGET',637,null);

commit;
```

My Attempt:

```sql
SELECT e_id,
       LISTAGG(source, ';') source,
       LISTAGG(target, ';') target,
       source_other
  FROM (SELECT e_id,
               CASE
                 WHEN sys_name = 'SOURCE' THEN
                  ref_id
               END source,
               CASE
                 WHEN sys_name = 'TARGET' THEN
                  ref_id
               END target,
               CASE
                 WHEN sys_name = 'SOURCE' AND ref_id IS NULL THEN
                  sys_other
               END source_other
          FROM source_det
         GROUP BY e_id);
```

From the above set of data I need only a single row to be returned from the `SELECT` query but I am getting `null` values instead along with the required values.
If `sys_name` is SOURCE then the result should be `ref_id`. If there is more than one record then it should be spilitted by delimiter ;
If `sys_name` is TARGET then result should be `ref_id`
If `sys_name` is SOURCE AND `ref_id` is null then it should give `sys_other` as a result. But from my query I am not getting a single row instead getting 4 rows. But ideally, I need only one row with `e_id` 11
And most important is in place of null values it could be possible that there would be `()` present in place of null. So, need to exclude this as well. After getting the desired result then we can use DECODE(ref_id,'()',null) like this.

Expected result:

| e_id | source | target | source_other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 992;637 | 637 | Manual |

Tool used: SQL Developer (18c)

Comment: For all columns in your SELECT statement, they either need to be part of an aggregate function (e.g. LISTAGG) or included in a GROUP BY clause. You have unaggregated columns, such as e_id, but no GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, just use like the following one below

```sql
SELECT e_id,
       LISTAGG(CASE
                 WHEN sys_name = 'SOURCE' THEN
                  ref_id
               END,
               ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ref_id DESC) AS source,
       LISTAGG(CASE
                 WHEN sys_name = 'TARGET' THEN
                  ref_id
               END,
               ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ref_id DESC) AS target,
       LISTAGG(CASE
                 WHEN sys_name = 'SOURCE' AND ref_id IS NULL THEN
                  DECODE(sys_other,'()','',sys_other)
               END,
               ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 0) AS source_other
  FROM source_det
 GROUP BY e_id
```

where missing **`WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ..)`** should follow `LISTAGG(...)` expression

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=34657b98bb9d900cd5710949f952e078)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for a quick turnaround. It worked for me but can we handle ```()``` in our query suppose if there are any ```()``` in place of null in ```ref_id```

Comment: Hi @Vicky , you're welcome. Do you mean [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ef750898f034e976e7f7d77b62c249ea) ..?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for this. And one thing how did you add Demo button of fiddle in your answer ??

Comment: @Vicky excuse me that I realised lately for the Demo button where I'm using `<kbd>[Demo](thelink)</kbd>`